# JS plugin to detect user's browser, OS, language, geolocation...?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I could have sworn that I saw this on Hacker News a few weeks ago: a simple JS plugin that gives you access to every common bit of information about your user - their OS, browser, language setting, etc.

I'm pretty sure it was a commercial product that was then immediately copied and open-sourced by someone on HackerNews.

But I now can't for the life of me remember what either the commercial product, or the open source plugin, were called.

Can anyone suggest either?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

you can use the [navigator object](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_browser.asp) to accomplish most of that.

for example you can do things like this:

```
txt = "<p>Browser CodeName: " + navigator.appCodeName + "</p>";
txt+= "<p>Browser Name: " + navigator.appName + "</p>";
txt+= "<p>Browser Version: " + navigator.appVersion + "</p>";
txt+= "<p>Cookies Enabled: " + navigator.cookieEnabled + "</p>";
txt+= "<p>Platform: " + navigator.platform + "</p>";
txt+= "<p>User-agent header: " + navigator.userAgent + "</p>";
```

but the plugin you are probably looking for is [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/docs/#whatis)

Comment: thanks! this library also had country geolocation, which is actually the main thing I'm looking for, plus a bunch of other stuff... looked really handy...

Comment: geolocation is included in that object: http://merged.ca/iphone/html5-geolocation

Comment: Word of caution: `navigator` is not a foolproof way of getting these details. The `userAgent` etc can well be faked. But yes, this is the simplest way.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for statistics rather than specific information per user, you could use non-intrusive tools like [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics) to get data on browser and OS usage etc.